# Как обойти блокировку телеграма?

Tags: python, telegram

Пишу телеграм-бота, проблемы с блокировкой.

Пишу так:

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https' : '52.179.18.244:8080'}
```

Выдает следующее сообщение:

```
2020-05-27 15:20:31,790 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ProxyError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bots/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Полина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Полина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 930, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Полина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 316, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "C:\Users\Полина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in _tunnel
    raise OSError("Tunnel connection failed: %d %s" % (code,
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Proxy Authentication Required, надо логин пароль\кредсы для прокси. Ну или вместо этого впн включить :)

Comment: @Evgeniy Здравствуйте! Не совсем поняла, что нужно конкретно сделать. Какие конкретные шаги нужно проделать?

Comment: можно не подключаться к прокси внутри программы, можно на компьютере включить впн, и потом запускать бота @Qpz